# (JS) How to pass value to child window from parent window (Internet Explore, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

I want to pass data from parent window to child window 
when using window.open  (popup new window)

Originally, I wrote code as below

Parent Window Side

```js
var orignalTextPopup = window.open("popup/orignalText", '_blank', 'width=900,height=700,scrollbars=yes');
orignalTextPopup.data = data;
```

Child Window Side

```js
fn_showOrginalText(window.data);
```

It works fine with chrome, But in Internet Explorer environment 
it doesn't work. How can I pass the value to child window ??
Please help me :'(

Comment: You could pass the data as a [query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to the new page.

Comment: @Pete Thanks for advice !

Comment: @Olian04 I think if I use query parameter it would be restricted to length limit.

Comment: I highly doubt that. The HTTP protocol doesn't have a "maximum query string length", and the smallest length in modern browsers to date is [81k characters and belongs to Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string).